# Excel select records based on multiple field values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

How do I select records based on multiple field values in an Excel table, eg, to answer the following question: "Identify all the transactions in which Jen sold lipstick in the East region". Therefor I have to identify records where name=Jen product=lipstick and location=east.

Comment: Use filter? [Filter data in a range or table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/filter-data-in-a-range-or-table-01832226-31b5-4568-8806-38c37dcc180e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) or [Advanced Filter](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/advanced-filter.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter the data by going to Data on the ribbon, highlighting the headers, and clicking filter. Then, for each relevant drop down, uncheck "Select All" and then recheck "Jen", "lipstick", and "east" for each relevant column.

This will hide all rows not matching your three criteria.

Comment: Thank you, nice easy solution

Comment: Happy to help! If this solution works for you, you should mark it as answered so that others with a similar issue can find it and learn from it too.